# Image with link, link is bigger than expected. Is it possible to make an ([a class="name"]) for links?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

**EDIT: Thanks to everyone who has tried to help me out**

**JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/m3Lju7fk/**

My code is simple. please help, the link i put on an image is bigger than the actual image. Is it possible to make an a class for links?

HTML
`<a href="url"><img src="/ds2.png" class="d2"/></a>`

CSS

```
a:link {
  color: #0095F6;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0095F6;
}

a:visited {
  color: #0095F6;
}

a:active {
  color: #0095F6;a:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]
Dont ask why i have two hover links my program forces me to have it. If thats the issue please tell me below

Comment: What do you mean by this? - "Is it possible to make an a class for links?"

Comment: Is it possible to make a class for this (ex) <a href="url" class="name"> </a>

Comment: Yes, but do you have any problems implementing that? Your problem is not readily apparent; how is the link bigger than the image? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, is this SCSS or another preprocessor for CSS? If so, you are missing one `}`. If not, you have a syntax error. Which is the program that forces you to have two hover selectors?

Comment: Basically the link is not in the image, let me edit a picture fast, im on bootstrap studio but its not the issue

Comment: is it possible to resize a link?

Comment: @MrLister i found my issue it is because my image is (display: block). how do i make the link resize to fit the image?

Comment: Can you change the display to `inline-block`?

Comment: i have already tried but it makes it no longer centered

Comment: Then center the `a`, or whatever container the `a` is in.

Comment: i have done this so far a.center { display: inline-block but after this how do i center it? like I cant

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I'm still worried about the errors in the CSS. Maybe that is what causing problems.

Comment: @ysrfaith yes please replicate your code to codepen, jsfiddle or some other site for a quick solution.

Comment: I am so sorry for no replies I was asleep, I am currently coding a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3Lju7fk/

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 here is the jsfiddle

Comment: @MrLister https://jsfiddle.net/m3Lju7fk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the `<a>` to the center, what you need to do is assign `text-align:center` to whatever container it is in. In this example (from your fiddle), that would be the `body`.

And you have `margin-top: 80xp` on the image, but that causes the area above the img to be clickable as well. If you don't want that, move the `margin-top` to the `<a>`. That way, only the img itself is clickable.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.f1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.d2 {
  width: 50px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="url" class="f1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="d2" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to use flex if you want to align vertical too.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 80vh;
  /* adjust height as per your convenience */
}

.f1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="url" class="f1">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="d2"/>
</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but im not trying to do this look at my pic above, see how in the link is bigger than the image? I want my link to be the same size as my image only

Comment: I did what you showed as per image. Here, you have to be very specific from the start in order for others to help you. :)

Comment: hm, thats odd because on your code snippet the link is still outside of the image. Sorry if I was mistaken. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: No problem, we all learn that way. I was very terrible user initially. FYI, you can also full screen the snippet for better view.

Comment: thanks, if you dont know the solution to my problem its fine, it wasnt necessary, thanks for trying though :)

Comment: don't worry, please check now